# Formatting .htaccess RewriteCond / RewriteRule for removing query string from URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have developed a PHP site, which uses _GET variables to construct individual product pages. The current structure of the URLs for the (live) site is as follows:

http://campbellssweets.com/shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=Bacon+and+Cheddar+Popcorn

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the proper way to construct the RewriteCond and/or RewriteRule in my .htaccess file to remove the 'product.php' and the query string from the example above?

2) Similarly, how might I go about replacing the '+' with dashes so that the final URL is displayed as:

http://campbellssweets.com/shop/popcorn/Bacon-and-Cheddar-Popcorn

*For what it is worth, I am utilizing the 'index.php saved in a sub-folder' method to remove the '.php' from the category pages.*

I really appreciate the help!

**I have added the current work flow below to hopefully better explain my question. Apologies if I am doing something wrong here, it's my first post**

I have a category page that lists all of the items in the database via a loop. The page is saved as index.php:

```
/shop/popcorn/index.php
```

Each of the items listed in the category page link to individual product pages (product.php), which is in the same directory as the category page. The (product.php) page is dynamic and its content is dependent on the value of the $_GET variable: The link from main category page that generates the product.php page is as follows:

```
<a href="product.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($list_savory["product_name"]); ?>">
```

The product page URL's (which are the focus of this question), were displaying as:

**shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=Bacon+and+Cheddar+Popcorn**

I was trying to figure out the correct .htaccess code that would remove query string from the URL and replace the '+' with dashes so they would instead display as:

**shop/popcorn/Bacon-and-Cheddar-Popcorn**

Ravi's answer does format the URL'S in the way that I requested, but the page fails to load and I get a '404 Not Found' error - even after I successfully modified the product.php conditional to accept the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead of the $_GET variable.

I hope that helps clear everything up. Sorry again for the confusion, I'm new at this.

Comment: Do a search here or on a search engine for "PHP routing" - you'll get loads of results then `:)`.

Comment: (To _literally_ scour the web, does one use a [Brillo pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillo_pad)? `:-D`)

Comment: Hyperbole removed. Thanks halfner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `.htaccess` is in the web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)subject=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/product.php$ $1/%2? [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)((?:[+\s]+).*)$ $1-$2$3 [DPI,N]
RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,DPI,L]
```

***EDIT** : (Parsing the URI for keywords)*

Chris, the idea is to now capture the subject from path info instead of a `GET` parameter because it's not being passed as `?subject=sub+info` which makes it unavailable as `$_GET['subject']` now.

You'd need to get the subject keywords from the URI path as follows:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$subject = substr($uri, strrpos($, "/"));
```

***EDIT** : (two-way redirection)*

Add the following after the rules defined above.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/popcorn)/([^/.]+)$ $1/product.php?subject=$2&no-redir [NC,L]
```

Notice, I've added another `RewriteCond` on `%{QUERY_STRING}` above. This also means you can revert your `product.php` to the way it was before since `subject` is being passed again as usual.

Comment: That code worked perfectly to reformat the URL's, however I am now getting a 404 Server Error. The landing page has a conditional to check if the $subject variable isset before the page loads - would the reformatted URL (without the 'subject=') affect the conditional?

Comment: Yes, it would. The landing page won't recognize subject unless passed as `?subject=`. I think formatting the url as `/shop/popcorn/?subject=Bacon-and-Cheddar-Popcorn` should work. Your call. Shorten it to just `s` if you like or pass as `/?Bacon-and..`. Your php would have to accommodate accordingly. I would suggest you keep the pretty url and use lastIndexOf "/" with sub-string to capture the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ravi, is 'lastIndexOf"/" with sub-string' a JavaScript function? I am not familiar with a PHP function of that name. If you could provide any direction or links on how to use that technique I would be very appreciative.

Comment: @Chris, those were Java equivalents of PHP `strrpos()` and `substr()`. Please, have a look at my update. That's the change I'm proposing for your landing php page.

Comment: Ravi, I was able to utilize the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable to satisfy the conditional

Comment: Ravi, I was able to utilize the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable (as opposed to the $_GET variable) to satisfy the conditional statement - so thank you for that technique. With that being said, the .htaccess code above still results in a 404 Error. Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: @Chris, I didn't understand that if you're receiving the subject then it means the redirection did hit your PHP. So, how's it a 404? Please, post some more details on your flow.

Comment: I have edited the question to describe the flow / code much more clearly

Comment: The above code works in formatting the URL's and redirecting the page, but the $_GET variable is not being received. The pages now load (No more 404 errors) but they're just 'shells' without the $_GET variable.

Comment: Can anyone figure why I would be failing to receive the $_GET variable from the .htaccess code above?

Comment: @Chris, I think you should close this question and open a new one. Not only this falls more in the realms of PHP than htaccess you'd receive fresh views on your problem as well. Your original question (about changing `+` to `-` and back) I believe has already been answered.